# Date and time conversion query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In my database table, there is a date column i.e. EXPECTED DATE which is in dd-mm-yyyy format, and the datatype of the column is text. Now, I want to convert the format to yyyy-mm-dd. But the date is not changing at all and also  when I tried to get the timestamp for the expected date column . I am getting some errors. For date coming I have used this STR_TO_DATE. But the year is not coming like what I expect and the timestamp also.

For example:

```
select STR_TO_DATE ('30-11-2011', '%d,%m,%y') as date ;
```

returns a result as

```
2020-11-30
```

And for timestamp

```
select STR_TO_DATE ('2011,11,30 12,30,45', '%y,%m,%d, %H,%I,%S');
```

I am not getting errors.

Please help me get the correct answers for this problem.

Comment: could you please specify RDBMS you use. Time-arithemic and conversion are vendor-dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query you need to use the %Y. Remember that it is always better to use "Y" for the years when you are writing a query for year.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("30,11,2011", "%d,%m,%Y");
```

For the second one also, you can use '%Y' in the place of '%y'. For minutes, use '%i' not '%I'. For hours and minutes, you can use whatever you like.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2011,11,30 12,30,45", "%Y,%m,%d %h,%i,%s");
```

Refer to the below [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) for more clarification on SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need `%Y` (capital Y) for the 4 digit year, when using MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE`.  Also, minutes is represented by `%i`, not `%I`, the latter which is hours on a 0 to 12 scale.  So use:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('30-11-2011', '%d-%m-%Y');
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2011,11,30 12,30,45', '%Y,%m,%d %H,%i,%S');
```

Comment: P.S. Also the `,` after `%d` is gone. This will help when you copy the statement from the question and still wonder why the replacements "not work"....

Answer (score -1):

For the first query you need to use the %Y'.

SELECT STR_TO_DATE("30,11,2011", "%d,%m,%Y");

For minutes, use this one only '%i'.

SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2011,11,30 12,30,45", "%Y,%m,%d %h,%i,%s");

Comment: Downvoted as being a total copy of the other two answers which were posted 2 days earlier.  This answer adds zero new information.